# Let $A=\{0,1\}$. How many strings of length $5$ are in $A^*$ where at least two $1$ are next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $A=\{0,1\}$. How many strings of length $5$ where at least two $1$ next to each other are there in $A^*$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an ugly/inconvenient direct count, by breaking them up into instances by the maximum consecutive instances of $1$'s.

**Strings where only $11$ appears:**

1) A single $11$, no other $1's$: Obviously $11000$ is such a string. We can permute this in ${4 \choose 1}=4$ ways to obtain all strings with exactly one $11$ in it. (+4)

2) A single $11$, with single $1$'s: $11010,11001,01101$ and their mirror images. (+6)

3) Two disjoint $11$'s: The only possible one is $11011$. (+1)

**Strings where only $111$ appears:**

4) We count the number of reconfigurations of $11100$ with no extra $1$'s, ${3\choose 1}=3$. (+3)

5) With single $1$'s: $11101,10111$. (+2)

**Strings where only $1111$ appears:**

6) We count the number of reconfigurations of $11110$, ${2\choose 1}=2$. (+2)

**Strings where only $11111$ appears:**

7) Obviously, 1. (+1)

So there are, $4+6+1+3+2+2+1=19$ strings.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: it's easier to count the opposite (the number of strings of length five that do not contain "11") and subtract that number from the total number of strings of length five.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the total number of possible strings, and then subtract the number of strings that do *not* contain *any* appearance of $11$.

Lets consider a more general case, where the strings you are interested in have length $n$ (in your case $n=5$). 
We want to count the number $T(n)$ of strings that do *not* have $11$ in them.
Any such sequence (like any binary string), will start with either $0$ or $1$.

- If it starts with $0$, then the next entry (second bit) can be either $0$ or $1$; there is no restriction. Therefore, the remaining $n-1$ entries can be any binary string of length $n-1$ not containing consecutive ones. How many such sequences are there? Based on our definition, $T(n-1)$.
- If it starts with $1$, then we know that the next entry cannot be $1$ because then there would be a $11$ in the sequence. The second entry *has* to be $0$, and we only have the freedom to choose the value of the remaining $n-2$ entries. Of course, once again, we have to do that in a way that the substring of length $n-2$ also does not contain $11$. Hence, the number of such strings is $T(n-2)$.

The above cover all possible cases. We conclude that
$$
T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2).
$$
You are interested in $T(n)$ for $n=5$. But you should be able to determine $T(n)$ for smaller values of $n$ (e.g. $n=2$ and $3$) and build up from there..

Then, the total number of valid strings is
$$
 \#\lbrace\text{All possible strings}\rbrace - T(5).
$$
By the way, I find that this recursive way of building things comes handy in many cases when you want to count things. So keep it in mind!